# How can I connect to vimeo by using my website with PHP, Javascript or an API?

Tags: javascript, php, connection, embed, vimeo

I'm currently working on a website, and I would like to add automatically the most recent video uploaded on my vimeo account. I found out that I have to use in a first place, an API, but I don't know any API which can do that. So I came up with this idea :

1 - First, connect to my vimeo account with php or javascript etc... from my website in the case to end up to the management page.

2 - Get the HTML with the DOM, I found the ID of the video in the url of the videos.

3 - Create a function that replace automatically the ID of the URL in the  from the video that vimeo gives you on my website.

The code that vimeo gives you :

```
<iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/563338183?badge=0&amp;autopause=0&amp;player_id=0&amp;app_id=58479" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; fullscreen; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen style="position:absolute;top:0;left:0;width:40%;height:40%;" title="HIEBEL_GRAND VITRAIL_0621_57400"></iframe><script src="https://player.vimeo.com/api/player.js"></script>
```

The URL of a video from vimeo :

```
https://vimeo.com/manage/videos/123456789/1234a56789
```

To get there, I have to be connected.

The connection pop-up :
[image: image of the home page of vimeo with the connection pop up and the HTML]

I found some Jquery function on the web, but I think that it's not for what I'm looking for :

```
jQuery(function($){
    $('#result').load('https://vimeo.com/fr/');
});
```

If you guys have a solution, I'll be very grateful

Comment: Surely you can [sort the data returned](https://developer.vimeo.com/api/reference/videos#get_videos) either asc/desc  and select the last item??

Comment: oh, ok, I didn't know about that. Thanks, that will help a lot!

Comment: TBH I have never worked with the Vimeo API but that is just what I saw looking at their documentation.

Comment: I've found this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46582015/vimeo-api-get-request-in-javascript but it seems really complicated just for that. I don't understand why they didn't think about a simple thing like that...

Comment: Alas I cannot run any test scripts as I have not uploaded any videos to Vimeo. I did run the query I mentioned with a few parameters set and the response suggests the data of interest will be within the json.data array. The question you linked to made a point regarding hiding your `authorisation accesstoken` - though for you this might not be applicable as all you need to run the query is your userId number in the url.

Comment: After testing this code :

`var XHR = new XMLHttpRequest();`
`XHR.open('get', 'https://api.vimeo.com/users/9298174/videos');`
`XHR.send();`

`XHR.addEventListener('readystatechange', function() {`
    `if (XHR.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE && XHR.status === 200) {`
        `let location = JSON.parse(XHR.responseText);`
        `console.log(location);'
    `}`
`})`

I must have the authorization :

`Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 401 (Unauthorized)`

Comment: OK - so the comments made in the question to which you linked DO apply. Create a proxy on your server to fetch the actual data so that your secret token stays secret.

Comment: Ok, thank you for your support, I have my answer and I posted the whole code (without the token and the ID obviously). It works perfectly, so if your interested, you can check it out bellow :)

Comment: Glad you have sorted this

Answer (score 1):

Ok guys, after trying a lot and looking for a working code, I finally got it!

That's the key :

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import axios from "axios";

const CLIENT_IDENTIFIER = "***INSERT CLIENT ID***";
const CLIENT_SECRET =
  "***INSERT TOKEN***";

class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    vimeo: []
  };

  async getVideosForChannel(access_token) {
    const { data } = await axios.get(
      "https://api.vimeo.com/channels/***CHANNEL NAME***/videos?sort=date&direction=desc",
      {
        headers: {
          Authorization: `Bearer ${access_token}`
        }
      }
    );

    this.setState({ vimeo: data.data });
  }

  async componentDidMount() {
    if (!CLIENT_IDENTIFIER || !CLIENT_SECRET) {
      return alert("Please provide a CLIENT_IDENTIFIER and CLIENT_SECRET");
    }

    try {
      const { data } = await axios.post(
        "https://api.vimeo.com/oauth/authorize/client",
        { grant_type: "client_credentials" },
        {
          auth: {
            username: CLIENT_IDENTIFIER,
            password: CLIENT_SECRET
          }
        }
      );

      this.getVideosForChannel(data.access_token);
    } catch (error) {
      if (error.response.status === 429) {
        alert(
          "The Vimeo api has received too many requests, please try again in an hour or so"
        );
      }
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <ul>
          {this.state.vimeo.map(({ resource_key, link, name }) => (
            <li key={resource_key}>
              <a id="lien" href={link}>
                {name}
              </a>
              <p>{link}</p>
            </li>
          ))}
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

You gotta make sure that react is install to make it work.

( thanks to this dude https://codesandbox.io/s/pwro9p7w8j?file=/src/index.js )